# まとめられたデータフレームを展開する

Tags: r, dplyr

Rを使用しています。

```
no1,no2,
  1, 14,
  3, 25,
  4, 43,
  6, 65,
```

のようなデータフレームがありますが、これはno1=1,2のときno2=14、no1=4,5のときno2=43です。（3つ以上同じ数が連続して省略されることもあります。）
どのようにすれば

```
no1,no2,
  1, 14,
  2, 14,
  3, 25,
  4, 43,
  5, 43,
  6, 65,
```

のような形に変換できるでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tidyr` パッケージの `fill` 関数を使うと、 NA値をその列の直前の NA でない値で埋められます。

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)
> df1 <- dplyr::data_frame(no1 = c(1L,  3L,  4L,  6L),
+                          no2 = c(14L, 25L, 43L, 65L))
> dplyr::data_frame(no1 = 1:6) %>%
+       dplyr::left_join(df1, by = "no1") %>%
+       tidyr::fill(no2)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
   no1   no2
  <int> <int>
1     1    14
2     2    14
3     3    25
4     4    43
5     5    43
6     6    65
```

### [2017/06/29]コメントを受け追記

> 元データが3スタートの場合1,2のデータがNAになってしまうのですが、何かいいアイデアあるでしょうか？1,2にも3の値を‌​入れる形でかまわないです。 – user87562

不格好ですが、以下ではどうでしょうか。`fill`関数を逆方向にもう1回実行する方針です。

```
> df1 <- dplyr::data_frame(no1 = c(3L,  4L,  6L), no2 = c(25L, 43L, 65L))
> dplyr::data_frame(no1 = 1:6) %>%
+        dplyr::left_join(df1, by = "no1") %>% 
+        tidyr::fill(no2) %>% 
+        tidyr::fill(no2, .direction = "up")
# A tibble: 6 x 2
    no1   no2
  <int> <int>
1     1    25
2     2    25
3     3    25
4     4    43
5     5    43
6     6    65
```

Comment: データフレームをつくって`left_join()`しているところは、`complete(df1, no1 = full_seq(no1, period = 1L))`という書き方もできます。参考までに。

Comment: なるほどfull_seq...!
ありがとうございます！！

Comment: 元データが3スタートの場合1,2のデータがNAになってしまうのですが、何かいいアイデアあるでしょうか？1,2にも3の値を入れる形でかまわないです。

Comment: @user87562 追記しました。